# how set quickly set photo size fit to frame size in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

when i have dragging a photo into a new document, it may be bigger or smaller in size than new created document and i have to resize the picture via ctrl + t. i seeking for a way or a shortcut to pressing and quickly image fit to document borders. is there any way?
[image]

Comment: It sounds to me like what you're doing is better suited to InDesign.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to scale the image to the document, or adjust the document to be the size of the image?

**Image to Document**

When you're transforming the image, grab one of the corners. Hold ALT + SHIFT while you're dragging to scale proportionally from the middle of the image.

**Document to Image**

The fastest way (that I know of) is to copy the image, open a new document, and under presets there's an option for "Clipboard". Then paste your image into the new document.

Answer (score 0):

Open photoshop -> Create a new document. Then open the folder in which your images are placed for example in D drive. Then drag and drop the image from the folder into the psd document. This will automatically resize your image according to the canvas size.

Answer (score 0):

I am the new comer in Photoshop world, same thing I have been going through which you were.
I got the solution by my own, follow the steps..

1. Create new file
2. Open **File** menu.
3. Click **Place**  option.
4. Select Image.
5. Click on Place button.
6. According scale of selected Image will fit into the frame.

[image: how to auto fit large scale image into photoshop fram]